# Rails migration mass change value based on current value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've ran into an issue: I had a mistype in my select_tag dropdown, so table got filled with a good number of entries that carried it over into DB. Now that mistype was fixed, I need to find a way to mass fix the values in my db. How do I do this?

I was thinking to use some conditional statement, but I'm rather new to rais, and all I've used in past for similar task was `article.title = "text" unless article.title.blank?`, but I can't figure out how to repurpose it for what I need to do.

Comment: im having trouble understanding what the actual problem is but if its a mass mistype in the db, i feel like you can figure this out. maybe you don't have a clear understanding of what you can do with the db and the ORM so try starting there as well as making sure you have a good understanding of ruby basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [update_all](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all).

```
Article.where(:title => nil).update_all(:title => "text")
```

This will find all `Articles` that have a blank title, and give *just those items* a title of "text".

Comment: So if I want to replace values I'd use smth like
`Article.where(:title => 'sometitle').update_all(:title => "text")`

Comment: @user3735111 Yes that will find all Articles that have "sometitle" as their title, and update just those records to now have a title of "text". All other Articles will be left alone.